# Setting text of one dropdown according to option value of another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox to set the time to 24 or 12 hour formats.  If the user checks or unchecks this I want the current time to be set to the same time in the alternate time format. So if time is currently 17:00 it should be set to 5.00pm. At present it just sets it back to the first option value. This is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/21d9vcsr/15/).

```
<input type="checkbox" id="isCheckedFormat">24 Hour</p>

<select id="time1">

</select>


var a = ['12.00','13.00','14.00','15.00','16.00','17.00'];
var b = ['12.00','1.00pm','2.00pm','3.00pm','4.00pm','5.00pm'];
var d = [];

$('#isCheckedFormat').click(function() { 
    currenttime = $("#time1").val();
    console.log(currenttime);    
    if($('#isCheckedFormat').is(':checked')){
     d = a;
     c = 1;   
     $('#time1 option').remove();
     for(var i = 0; i<d.length; i++) {
            $('#time1').append('<option val="'+ c +'">'+d[i]+'</option>');
             c++;
         }
      $('#time1 option[val="currenttime"]').prop('selected',true);  

    }else{
     d = b;
     c = 1;
        $('#time1 option').remove();
     for(var i = 0; i<d.length; i++) {
            $('#time1').append('<option val="'+ c +'">'+d[i]+'</option>');
             c++;
    }
    $('#time1 option[val="currenttime"]').prop('selected',true);
 };   
});
```

How can you set the time correspondingly?

Comment: you should consider using [momentJs](http://momentjs.com/). as it can become pretty hectice to manage the time in array like format. an Try to use `$.change` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do that

```
var a = ['12.00','13.00','14.00','15.00','16.00','17.00'];
var b = ['12.00','1.00pm','2.00pm','3.00pm','4.00pm','5.00pm'];

function populate(e) {
    var val = $('#time1').find('option:selected').index(),
        sel = $('#time1').empty();

    $.each(e.target.checked ? b : a, function(i, time) {
        $('<option />', {
            value : time,
            text  : time,
            prop  : {
                selected : i === val
            }
        }).appendTo(sel);
    });
}

$('#isCheckedFormat').on('change', populate).trigger('change')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/21d9vcsr/18/)

You're getting the values of the options, trying to reset the option etc. but you change the value when you change the option text, so that never matches. I've decided to use the index instead, which is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Add only 2 lines:

1) One line to **save the index** of the current selected value:

```
var x = $('#time1').find('option:selected').index();
```

2) One line to **set the selected value** using the saved index:

```
$('#time1').val(d[x]);
```

---

The code will be something like this:

```
...
$('#isCheckedFormat').click(function() { 
    ...
    console.log(currenttime);
    var x = $('#time1').find('option:selected').index();   // ADDED
    if($('#isCheckedFormat').is(':checked')){
        ...
    }else{
         ...
         for(var i = 0; i<d.length; i++) {
                $('#time1').append('<option val="'+ c +'">'+d[i]+'</option>');            
                $('#time1').val(d[x]);                    // ADDED
                c++;
        }
        ...
    };   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is only a quick fix, your setup as a whole seems a bit inconvenient.

```
var a = ['12.00','13.00','14.00','15.00','16.00','17.00'];
var b = ['12.00','1.00pm','2.00pm','3.00pm','4.00pm','5.00pm'];
var d = [];

$('#isCheckedFormat').click(function() { 
    currenttime = $("#time1").val();
    element = $("#time1 option:selected").index();
    console.log(currenttime);    
    if($('#isCheckedFormat').is(':checked')){
         d = a;
         c = 1;   
        $('#time1 option').remove();
         for(var i = 0; i<d.length; i++) {
                $('#time1').append('<option val="'+ c +'">'+d[i]+'</option>');
                 c++;
             }
          $('#time1 option:eq('+element+')').prop('selected',true);  

    }else{
        d = b;
        c = 1;
            $('#time1 option').remove();
         for(var i = 0; i<d.length; i++) {
                $('#time1').append('<option val="'+ c +'">'+d[i]+'</option>');
                 c++;
        }
        $('#time1 option:eq('+element+')').prop('selected',true);
    };   

});
```